# What does `.into()` do when called on `RawOrigin:Signed(who)` and how does the context affect it?

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

I have seen `.into()` used several times like `frame_system::RawOrigin::Signed(who).into()`. From what I understand it does some conversion but the [docs for into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/core/convert/mod.rs.html#553-560) do not make it clear (to me) how to know what it is converting to. For context a [specific example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/sudo/src/lib.rs#L208) I am interested in comes from `sudo_as()` in the sudo module.

```
        fn sudo_as(origin, who: <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source, call: Box<<T as Trait>::Call>) {
            // This is a public call, so we ensure that the origin is some signed account.
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            ensure!(sender == Self::key(), Error::<T>::RequireSudo);

            let who = T::Lookup::lookup(who)?;

            let res = match call.dispatch(frame_system::RawOrigin::Signed(who).into()) {
                Ok(_) => true,
                Err(e) => {
                    sp_runtime::print(e);
                    false
                }
            };

            Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::SudoAsDone(res));
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `into` will return "the right" type depending on the context from which it was called. In the example you provide, you can look at [the docs for the `dispatch` function](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0-alpha.7/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Dispatchable.html#tymethod.dispatch) and see that it requires an [`Origin`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0-alpha.7/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Dispatchable.html#associatedtype.Origin) as a parameter. However, as you can see the `who` variable is being used to create a [`RawOrigin`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0-alpha.7/frame_system/enum.RawOrigin.html) type. So the `into` function is being used to convert the provided type (`RawOrigin`) to whatever type is needed (`Origin`, in this case).

Comment: I think you can go a little further and see that under [**Blanket Implementations**](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0-alpha.7/frame_system/enum.RawOrigin.html#blanket-implementations) the `RawOrigin` type implements an `Into` trait for `T`, where `T` is an `AccountId`.

Comment: And even further, anything that implements `From` also implement `Into`.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html

`One should always prefer implementing From over Into because implementing From automatically provides one with an implementation of Into thanks to the blanket implementation in the standard library.`

Comment: Great, thanks! You guys explaining the docs helps me get a better understanding of how to read them.